# API design and storing custom queries from Db to cache

Tags: architecture, api-design, caching

I was thinking about how people actually implement utilising results from a cache before a doing database lookup. When designing an API, should there always be a manual check to the cache first before doing a database lookup? I've read many books and seen many videos online but I have never seen someone do it like that.

What is the best way to set up DB, in-memory data store and write your apis? I'm under the impression that most people make one request and the cache/db lookup should be automatically but not sure how its actually done.

Comment: You can implement it using decorator pattern, just in case you want a simple implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caching database results may or may not be something you want to do, according to the situation.  For example, if you want to retrieve live stock values to show the the user, it is obviously more important that the results are as fresh as possible.

Many libraries such as hibernate will automatically cache results unless you specify otherwise.  It is able to do so without creating problems, simply because you would also use hibernate to change these records, and therefore hibernate can know with certainty if a given record is up-to-date or not.  Most databases do the same in an attempt to optimize search times (you can determine this by performing the same query twice and noting the differences in time of execution).

Before you decide to cache anything, you should be fully knowledgeable about what's happening under the hood.  Caching something which is already being cached is simply a waste of resources.

I would strongly encourage you to cache any and everything which is not likely going to change often, and which won't occupy significant amounts of memory.  When you load the data from the database, you can create a timestamp indicating the time of access.  You can use this to say, force refresh of data after some period of time.  Though you may not likely want to refresh the data often, a web application which has an up-time of weeks or longer may still consider a refresh of at least once a day just the same.

While you could cache directly in your data layer, I would discourage it, as the data layer should only stupidly fetch data when requested, no more or no less.  The caching should be performed in a class specifically designed to give you the information you require, and it should be done in a transparent fashion, so the caller doesn't need to know there is an underlying cache.

> When designing an API, should there always be a manual check to the
>   cache first before doing a database lookup?

Assuming it is something you want cached, then yes.  If you think you'll need the most recent version, there is no point to using a cache in the first place.

> What is the best way to set up DB, in-memory data store and write your
>   apis?

Lets be clear, an in-memory database is entirely saved in memory.  If you're using this, caching loses it's advantage, because if it is in your cache, you're fetching from memory, and if it isn't in your cache, you're still fetching from memory.

Edit:  By request, expanding answer to answer comment made by @robertson.

### What types of caches are there?

Cache, by its essential nature, is about memorizing data to effectively reduce the operatings to retrieve said data because of being CPU intensive or slow.  So when we're talking about cache, this is always the objective.

The type of cache mentioned above with hibernate is what's called a write-back cache by default.  Since performing updates and inserts for every operation can get expensive, hibernate simply keeps a cache representing the difference between the database and what has been "changed" periodically committing all these changes to the database.  In other words, you grab Student entity and update its name from John to Paul, and another part of your program grabs that same Student entity, they will see Paul, but only because hibernate has it in memory.  If the power shutoff in that moment, you'd see no update to the database; that Student entity would still be named John.  This improves both reads and writes at the expense of potentially losing information.

To prevent such problems, there is also a write-through cache, which *does* update the database each and every time, but still returns a local version if it is in cache (so it improves reads significantly, but slightly slower writes).

You can have LRU cache which is how operating systems generally handle memory blocks.  LRU stands for "Least Recently Used" and it is the heuristic for picking and choosing blocks to discard in favor for newer blocks.  This works well when your cache is fixed, as is the case for PC memory.

There is also what is called memoization, which is a specialized cache for optimizing calls to specific methods in your program.  Caching the results of a call to fibonacci(5) and fibonacci(6) means a call to fibonacci(7) is merely retrieving results of a previous call and adding them together, effectively calculating once rather than perform a recursive and potentially expensive call.  Be careful when you use memoization as you need to have a clear idea how much memory you'll require in worst case scenarios!

HTTP caches are just following a http protocol where pages are given expiration dates, and if they're not expired, the pages are reloaded locally rather than downloaded from the server.  Unlike most caches, this isn't using memory for storage but the disk (as web latency could actually be worse than disk latency).

localStorage is not really a cache, in the sense that a cache is "about memorizing data to effectively reduce the operatings to retrieve said data because of being CPU intensive or slow".  In the same sense, session data is not a cache even if it is in memory, simply because it doesn't exist anywhere else (it's not an alternative to loading from the disk, for instance, because it isn't there!).

I'm not quite sure what you mean by proxy caches?  Could you elaborate?

Comment: thanks, i definitely had some confusion. just realised that something like Redis, although often talked about as a "cache" is still a database....albeit an in-memory one. Could you clarify a bit more on the types of "caches" available? I have read about quite a few, i know there are browser caches (session/localStorage), HTTP caches, proxy caches etc. thanks for any clarification.

Comment: @robertson Ok, expanded answer!

Comment: The other thing about caching is that it gets more complex with server farms. Redis less of an issue, but when you get "smart" things happening in your ORM or simplistic local caching it can get weird quickly.  Sometimes you need to fix the caching, sometimes adjust the server affinity depending on what's going wrong.